# Deleting Duplicates of grouped rows (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I'm looking for a way in which you delete duplicated groups of rows.
The below shows some product Specs which have been inputted overtime, the larger the input ID the later the input.

Apart from the Input code, 1001 and 1002 inputs are exactly the same, same code, same ingrdients and amounts etc. Most likely due to the spec having to be redone for a new year.

When this is the case, I need to only keep one version. The one with the highest Input ID.

How do I Delete Duplicated groupings?
I can't simply delete duplicates by row as per my example, It would affect 1003 which is a different product make up within the same code and therefore needs to be kept.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

What I have:

| Input ID | Code | Product | Ingrdnt | Amnt | Unit | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 001 | Lemonade | Sugar | 0.1 | L | 2 |
| 1001 | 001 | Lemonade | Lemon | 0.4 | L | 2 |
| 1001 | 001 | Lemonade | Water | 1.5 | L | 2 |
| 1002 | 001 | Lemonade | Sugar | 0.1 | L | 2 |
| 1002 | 001 | Lemonade | Lemon | 0.4 | L | 2 |
| 1002 | 001 | Lemonade | Water | 1.5 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Sugar | 0.1 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Lemon | 0.4 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Water | 1.3 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Rasberry | 0.2 | L | 2 |

What I need:

| Input ID | Code | Product | Ingrdnt | Amnt | Unit | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 001 | Lemonade | Sugar | 0.1 | L | 2 |
| 1002 | 001 | Lemonade | Lemon | 0.4 | L | 2 |
| 1002 | 001 | Lemonade | Water | 1.5 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Sugar | 0.1 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Lemon | 0.4 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Water | 1.3 | L | 2 |
| 1003 | 001 | Lemonade | Rasberry | 0.2 | L | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to groupby by InputID, transform groups into something that could be compared for duplication, and then find InputIDs that are unique

Here is how we figure out unique indices:

```
unique_group_ids = df.groupby('Input ID').apply(lambda g:tuple(g.drop(columns = 'Input ID').stack().tolist())).drop_duplicates(keep = 'last').index
unique_group_ids
```

output:

```
Int64Index([1002, 1003], dtype='int64', name='Input ID')
```

Now just index the original df with these indices

```
df.set_index('Input ID').loc[unique_group_ids].reset_index()
```

output:

```
      Input ID    Code  Product    Ingrdnt      Amnt  Unit      Weight
--  ----------  ------  ---------  ---------  ------  ------  --------
 0        1002       1  Lemonade   Sugar         0.1  L              2
 1        1002       1  Lemonade   Lemon         0.4  L              2
 2        1002       1  Lemonade   Water         1.5  L              2
 3        1003       1  Lemonade   Sugar         0.1  L              2
 4        1003       1  Lemonade   Lemon         0.4  L              2
 5        1003       1  Lemonade   Water         1.3  L              2
 6        1003       1  Lemonade   Rasberry      0.2  L              2
```